# How to fix connection failing in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, exchange-server, azure-powershell, exchange-server-2010

We are running our PowerShell Script in Remote Windows Server 2019. We use Connect-AzureAD and Connect-IPPSsesion. The script took about 3 hours to complete the whole process. It was working fine a few weeks ago but we're getting this error the past few day for some reason.

```
The connection to the specified remote host was refused. Verify that the WS-Management service is running on the remote host and configured to listen for requests on the correct port and HTTP URL. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

It able to connected when the script start but we got that error during the process and stop the script.

I've been google the past few days and I found this documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/administration/fail-to-start-exchange-management-shell-console

I've tried the following

- I've try to do the solutions that it provided in doc but there is no IIS and
  MSExchangePowerShellAppPool in our Remote Desktop.
- I checked the User and it has the remotepowershell enabled (Always has been)
- I checked WinRM QuickConfig and it set up properly
- I change our proxy address to a different proxy address

but still no luck so any suggestion or help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By default, MSExchangePowerShellAppPool without running this application it is complex to find a solution. If you don't have MS Exchange PowerShell in your Desktop, please try the below.

Try using below ***cmdlet*** with ***Windows PowerShell***

```
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://<ServerFQDN>/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserCredential
Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking
```

Reference: [Connect to a remote Exchange server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-servers-using-remote-powershell?view=exchange-ps)

**Alternatively,** you can use [***EMTshooter***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/administration/connecting-remote-server-failed#about-the-emt-shooter) The local (target) Exchange server's EMTshooter programme runs there and looks for any issues that might affect the management tools attached to it.

- Make sure ipv4 is used for communication and `C:\Windows\system32\iis_ssi.dll`  exists.